# how to count a 0 modulus in a list

Tags: python, count, modulus

I have created a list and an iteration loop for this list. I am trying to count all the even numbers using the modulus operator.  I have initialised the count variable and used the count increment and an if statement to catch all the even numbers in a nested loop. However all I get is the number one. count equals 1, is this because of using modulus incorrectly, and item = 10 , is this because of the iteration loop reaching its end of the list?

I don't know what to change, the code structure all looks ok to me.  I tried indenting the print function. This showed me that the modulus is catching the even numbers but the count is not totalling these.

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for item in list:
    count = 0
    if (item % 2 == 0):
        count = count + 1
print(count)
print(item)
print(list)
```

I expect the number 5 as the result of the program as there are 5 even numbers in the list

Comment: You're resetting the counter on each iteration

Comment: One can simplify this to `count = sum(item % 2 == 0 for item in list)`

Answer (score 5):

Put the `count=0` outside the for loop. Right now, you reinitialize count to 0 during each iteration of the for loop.

Also, don't name your variable as [`built-in`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) function names: In your case, don't use `list` as a variable name. Below, I am using `lst` for example.

*Minor other modifications:* You can just use `count += 1` instead of `count = count + 1`. The former is a concise way of writing. Also, you don't need to enclose the single condition in parentheses `()` in your case.

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
count = 0

for item in lst:
    if item % 2 == 0:
        count += 1 # equivalent to count = count + 1
print(count)
print(item)
print(lst)


# 5
# 10
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) and [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum) built-in function instead of manual iteration through the list:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
count = sum(n % 2 == 0 for n in lst)
print(lst)
print(count)
```

will print you:

> `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`
>
> `5`